# i can't center the object - invisible side

Tags: mesh

I can't center the object ( house ).

It's like if there would be an invisible side to it.

I tried to set the center to the Geometry, and to the Center of Mass, but it doesn't go to the right place.

I tried to change the pivot.

I used CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + C

I tried SHIFT + S

I tried the Set Origin

I'm running out of options.

Here is the .blend

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend uploads as it is more permanent.

Comment: Are you sure you were selecting the actual mesh and not the parent, which is an empty?